# Why am I getting a NameError when trying to shift some code to a facade?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had a lot of instance variables in a controller action and I'm trying to move them into a facade but I've ran into an error. I'm new to Rails, so I'm having a bit of trouble.

My app contacts the Open Weather API and returns some weather parameters (temperature, wind, humidity etc). The API call is handled in a service class and I'm trying to use the facade pattern and have some methods in a PORO that organise the returned data, which is then presented in my view. At the moment i'm getting a `NameError. undefined local variable or method 'temperature' for ForecastsController`. I'm new to this so any help would be much appreciated! My code is below.

app/services/open_weather_api.rb

```
class OpenWeatherApi
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://api.openweathermap.org"

  def initialize(city, appid)
    @options = { query: { q: city, APPID: appid } }
  end

  def my_location_forecast
    self.class.get("/data/2.5/weather", @options)
  end
end
```

app/facades/forecasts_facade.rb

```
class ForecastsFacade

  def initialize(temperature, weather_code, description, wind, humidity)
    @temperature = temperature
    @weather_code = weather_code
    @description = description
    @wind = wind
    @humidity = humidity
  end

  def temperature
    @temperature = @forecast.dig('main', 'temp').to_i - 273
  end

  def weather_code
    @weather_code = @forecast.dig('weather', 0, 'id').to_i
  end

  def description
    @description = @forecast.dig('weather', 0, 'description')
  end

  def wind
    @wind = @forecast.dig('wind', 'speed').to_i
  end

  def humidity
    @humidity = @forecast.dig('main', 'humidity')
  end
end
```

app/controllers/forecasts_controller.rb

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController

  TOKEN = Rails.application.credentials.openweather_key

  def current_weather
    @city = params[:q]
    if @city.nil?
      @forecast = {}
    else
      @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@city, TOKEN).my_location_forecast
    end
    @forecasts_facade = ForecastsFacade.new(temperature, weather_code, description, wind, humidity)
  end
end
```

app/views/forecasts/current_weather.html.erb

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <h1 class="title">The weather in GIFs</h1>

  <div class="search">
    <%= form_tag(current_weather_forecasts_path, method: :get) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, placeholder: "Enter a city", class: "search-field" %>
      <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "search-button" do %>
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <% if @forecasts_facade.forecast.dig('cod').to_i == 404 %>
    <p>Please use a valid city name!</p>
  <% elsif @forecasts_facade.forecast.dig('cod').to_i == 400 %>
    <p>Please type in a city name!</p>
  <% elsif @forecasts_facade.forecast == {} %>
  <% else %>
    <p class="weather-description"><%= "#{@forecasts_facade.city.capitalize}: #{@forecasts_facade.description}" %></p>
    <div class="gif-container"><%= image_tag(find_gif_url, class: "gif") %>
      <span class="temperature weather-attribute"><%= "#{@forecasts_facade.temperature}°C" %></span>
      <span class="wind weather-attribute"><%= "wind:#{(@forecasts_facade.wind * 3.6).to_i}km/h" %></span> <!-- converts to km/hr -->
      <span class="humidity weather-attribute"><%= "humidity:#{@forecasts_facade.humidity}%" %></span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

app/helpers/forecasts_helper.rb

```
module ForecastsHelper
  GIFS = {
    thunder:
      {codes: [200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 221, 230, 231, 232],
       urls: %w(
          https://media.giphy.com/media/26uf5HjasTtxtNCqQ/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/vS09bj1KrXwje/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/l41YsrmiyeNZtmecw/giphy.gif
)},
    light_rain:
      {codes: [300, 301, 302, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 321, 500, 501, 520, 521],
       urls: %w(
          https://media.giphy.com/media/xT9GEz2CeU9uaI2KZi/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/l0Expn6D0D3g9NExq/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/14d8cRr25KPxbG/giphy.gif
)},

  def find_gif_url
    GIFS.each do |key, value|
      if value[:codes].include? @weather_code
        return value[:urls].sample
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It would seem you're getting that error because you're calling `ForecastsFacade.new(temperature, weather_code, description, wind, humidity)`, but, like the error says, you don't define a method or variable named `temperature` (or `weather_code`, `description`, `wind`, or `humidity`). Where do you expect those values to be coming from?

Comment: @jvillian these methods are in `app/facades/forecasts_facade.rb`

Comment: Right, but not in `ForecastsController`, which is why you can't call those methods in `ForecastsController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want your controller to look more like:

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController

  TOKEN = Rails.application.credentials.openweather_key

  def current_weather
    @city = params[:q]
    if @city.nil?
      @forecast = {}
    else
      @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@city, TOKEN).my_location_forecast
    end
    @forecasts_facade = ForecastsFacade.new(@forecast)
  end
end
```

Then, your `ForecastsFacade` more like:

```
class ForecastsFacade

  attr_accessor *%w(
    forecast
  ).freeze

  def initialize(forecast)
    @forecast = forecast
  end

  def temperature
    @temperature = forecast.dig('main', 'temp').to_i - 273
  end

  def weather_code
    @weather_code = forecast.dig('weather', 0, 'id').to_i
  end

  def description
    @description = forecast.dig('weather', 0, 'description')
  end

  def wind
    @wind = forecast.dig('wind', 'speed').to_i
  end

  def humidity
    @humidity = forecast.dig('main', 'humidity')
  end

  def invalid_city?
    forecast.dig('cod').to_i == 404 
  end

  def missing_city?
    forecast.dig('cod').to_i == 400
  end

end
```

Then, in your view, it seems to be weird to do stuff like:

```
@forecasts_facade.forecast.dig('cod').to_i == 404
```

when the whole point is to hide this detail from the `view`. So, perhaps, something more like:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <h1 class="title">The weather in GIFs</h1>

  <div class="search">
    <%= form_tag(current_weather_forecasts_path, method: :get) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, placeholder: "Enter a city", class: "search-field" %>
      <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "search-button" do %>
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <% if @forecasts_facade.invalid_city? %>
    <p>Please use a valid city name!</p>
  <% elsif @forecasts_facade.missing_city? %>
    <p>Please type in a city name!</p>
  <% elsif @forecasts_facade.forecast.blank? %>
  <% else %>
    <p class="weather-description"><%= "#{@forecasts_facade.city.capitalize}: #{@forecasts_facade.description}" %></p>
    <div class="gif-container"><%= image_tag(find_gif_url, class: "gif") %>
      <span class="temperature weather-attribute"><%= "#{@forecasts_facade.temperature}°C" %></span>
      <span class="wind weather-attribute"><%= "wind:#{(@forecasts_facade.wind * 3.6).to_i}km/h" %></span> <!-- converts to km/hr -->
      <span class="humidity weather-attribute"><%= "humidity:#{@forecasts_facade.humidity}%" %></span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

It looks like you don't use that `elsif @forecasts_facade.forecast.blank?` branch. Not sure what's up wtih that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Much appreciated. That's throwing a `ArgumentError in Forecasts#current_weather. Nil location provided. Can't build URI. ` It might have something to do with my helper where the images are stored (have added that code to the question) but can't work out why

Comment: AH, fixed it by adjusting my helper :) Thanks again for your help!